# Eclipse plugin: New file wizard extending INewWizard, how to get selected project to create in it

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, wizard

I'm currently writing an eclipse plugin, and in it, I have a new project creation and a new file creation wizard.

In the new project wizard, I create it, so I have no problem getting it and creating new files in it. (like creating the Main class for your project)

But when I'm in my New file wizard, I have literally no idea how to select the right project, and I would like some help please. 
Since it is a wizard, I would like to avoid needing an opened editor, and since it's a new wizard, it doesn't have a handler so I can't get it from there...

Thank you in advance,
Cordially,

Comment: The standard New File and similar wizards show a tree on the first page of the wizard that lets you select the location for the new files - is this what you want?

Comment: I don't need a tree since i want to create it in the root folder, but i'll look into it. It doesn't hurt to have the possibility after all, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I looked at it from another approach and it feels quite stupid right now.

When you initialize your wizard, you get an init method that contains the workbench and the selection, so you can keep it.

```
private IWorkbench wb;
private IStructuredSelection sel;
@Override
public void init(IWorkbench workbench, IStructuredSelection selection) {
    wb = workbench;
    sel = selection;
}
```

Then, I had found a code snippet earlier on Eclipse website, linked under here, that I had to change a bit, and it does what I want it to do.

```
// Get selected resource (can get project from it)
// https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_access_the_active_project%3F
private IResource extractSelection() {
    Object element = sel.getFirstElement();
    if (element instanceof IResource)
        return (IResource) element;
    if (!(element instanceof IAdaptable))
        return null;
    IAdaptable adaptable = (IAdaptable)element;
    Object adapter = adaptable.getAdapter(IResource.class);
    return (IResource) adapter;
}
```

With this, I can get my project in my wizard by doing

```
IProject project = extractSelection().getProject();
```

Comment: You won't always get a selection. Sometimes nothing is selected when the wizard is started.